# WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT in wp-config.php seems to be ignored

Tags: memory

I am using **WordPress v.3.8.1** with WMPL (WordPress Multilingual Plugin) v.3.1.4 and WPML Media Pugin v.2.1.3.

In php.ini file I have...

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

I already have a info.php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` where I can see that `memory_limit = 512M`.

In wp-config.php file I have before wp-settings.php inclusion...

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '384M' );
```

When I am trying to use "Media Translation" I get this error after 50/400 media have been processed...

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 1939
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with my question but my `/wp-includes/plugin.php` file has **only 810 lines** of code!

Comment: Is the php.ini file you have in the wp-admin folder? I run into this issue often and I usually do as you do, define the memory in the config file and then go to wp-admin->php.ini and define it there too. That usually does it for me.

Comment: @gdaniel no, the php.ini is in /public_html/. I created another php.ini inside wp-admin folder and I get the same error :(

Comment: Not sure then. It might be a php/server setting causing conflict.